# Does ignite queue has some method to check if the queue created or not, just like the cache

Tags: java, ignite

Does ignite queue has some method to check if the queue created or not, just like the cache?

For ignite cache, i could use somethin like:

```
        if( txInfoCache.get(txType) == null ) {
            txInfoCache.put(txType, new TreeMap<Long, InfoRecord>());
        }
```

But when i try to use this to do with queue, it just create a new one

```
        CollectionConfiguration colCfg = new CollectionConfiguration();

        IgniteQueue<InfoRecord>  queue =
                ignite.queue("ResultRecordQueue_" + txType, 0, null);

        // never go into this judge
        if (queue == null) {
            queue = ignite.queue("ResultRecordQueue_" + txType, 0, colCfg);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand your code. First of all, the following code snippet determines if the `txInfoCache` cache contains an entry for the given key `txType` and if it does not contain an entry associated with the key, it associates the specified key with the given value.

```
if(txInfoCache.get(txType) == null) {
    txInfoCache.put(txType, new TreeMap<Long, InfoRecord>());
}
```

It can be changed to `txInfoCache.putIfAbsent(txType, new TreeMap<Long, InfoRecord>())`.
As for the second part of your question, I just checked Apache Ignite 2.4 and it works well. `Ignite.queue(String name, int cap, @Nullable CollectionConfiguration cfg)` method returns `null` if named queue does not exist and `CollectionConfiguration` is `null`. Please make sure that this queue was not created earlier.